# using session variables in SQL where

Tags: php, sql, session, where-clause

I am trying to retrieve data from database and print them. Here's my code

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE c_no='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['c'])."'.AND a_no='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['a'])."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$connect);

    echo "<table>";
    $num_of_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo $num_of_rows;
    for($k=0;$k<3;$k=$k+2){
        echo "<th>";
        echo mysql_field_name($result,$k);
        echo "</th>";       
    }
    while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$r["field1"]."</td><td>".$r["field2"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

This code gives the errors `mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`
`mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`
`mysql_field_name(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

Why is this ? My session varaibles work fine as when I use
`echo $_SESSION['user']['a']`; it works fine?  Is the problem in WHERE clause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE c_no = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['c'])."' AND a_no = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['a'])."'";
```

You have missed a space for a point.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked. Where have I missed a space ? I can't see where the mistake is so I copied your line. When there's a mistake like this is there a way I can detect it ?

Answer (score 1):

> First - MySQL is deprecated. Try using MySQLi (improved).
>
> Second - You're messing up with your queries.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I don't have reputations!

Comment: so wait. like every one else, untill you do